# Get Multiple Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a Node app that includes the [Request module](https://github.com/request/request). I need to fire off multiple requests and then perform an action when all have completed. At this time, I have:

```
const request = require('request');

let urls = [GetUrl('id1'), GetUrl('idX'), ...);
for (let url of urls) {
  let u = request.get(url);
  // now what?
}
```

I can't figure out what request.get returns. I know that it runs asynchronously. But I can't tell if its an ES 6 promise, or some promise library or something else entirely.

Can anyone tell me how to perform an action after ALL requests have finished?

Thanks!

Comment: request.get returns a [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) in the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) has the added benefit of allowing "throttling".

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-promise');  // since we'll be using promises

Promise.map(arrayOfUrls, function(url){
    return request(url)
        .then(function(data){
            return JSON.parse(data);        // format / manipulate your data
        })
}).then(function(results){
    // results will be an array of JSON objects
})
```

This will dispatch all the requests as fast as node can handle them. If it's your own server, that could be ok but to prevent a "Too Many Requests error", add the following to your `map` call

```
Promise.map(arrayOfUrls, function, { concurrency: 4 });
// no more than 4 requests will run at once. Thanks Bluebird
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) to promisfy the get function and wait for all jobs to complete

```
var Q = require("q");

var job = function(id) {
    return Q.nbind(reqest.get, GetUrl(id));
};

let urls = [job('id1'), job('idX'), ...]);
Q.all(urls)
.then(function(values) {
   ///do something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for all the responses, you cannot use a regular loop. And since you have all the urls in an array, it's best to use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each):

```
async.each(urls, function(url, eachCallback) {
  request.get(url, function(err) {
    // do something else
    eachCallback();
  }
}, function(err) {

  // Done
}
```

Basically, `async.each` accepts three parameters:

1. **urls** - An array of items to iterate
2. **func1** - A function that serves as the task to perform for each item. Whenever this function is invoked, two parameters are passed along:

   - **url** - An item from the array
   - **eachCallback** - A callback function for you to call whenever you want to say *Hey this task is done!*
3. **func2** - A function that will execute once you iterated all the items and all `eachCallback` functions are called.

Please do note that people tend to forget to call `eachCallback` in the tasks functions. this will result to `func2` not being executed.

---

If you do not wish to do it concurrently. You may use `async.eachSeries` instead. It does the same thing, except task functions are called sequentially, and only after you call `eachCallback`.

---

If you want to continue with using concurrent tasks. You might want to consider using `async.eachLimit` The difference between `eachLimit` and `each` is, `eachLimit` requires a number passed as parameter #2: (`async.eachLimit(urls, 10, func1, func2)`).

This is a good practice especially if you're doing things that exhausts machine resources (like doing HTTP requests). The example I gave in the above paragraph will execute `func1` concurrently 10 at a time.

---

You can read more on the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [co](http://test) too. it is generator based.

```
var co = require('co');
var request = require('request-promise');

co(function *() {
  var urls = ['http://a', 'http://b'];
  var results = yield urls.map(x => request(x));
  console.log(results);
});
```

BTW, you can use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for plomisify existing callback style library.

```
var co = require('co');
var promisifyAll = require('bluebird').promisifyAll;
var request = promisifyAll(require('request'), {multiArgs: true});

co(function *() {
  var urls = ['http://a', 'http://b'];
  var results = yield urls.map(x => request.getAsync(x));
  console.log(results.map(x => [x[0].statusCode, x[1]]));
});
```

Even if you will use the ES7 [async/await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait#await-and-parallelism), change is small.
Currently, the following needs Babel.

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import request from 'request-promise';

(async () => {
  let urls = ['http://foldl.com/', 'http://pig-brewing.com'];
   let results = await Promise.all(urls.map(x => request(x)));
  console.log(results);
})();
```